# createuser command for postgres failing on windows

Tags: postgresql

I installed postgresql on Windows.  When I run createuser in the DOS prompt, it fails with the following error:

```
createuser testuser

could not connect to database postgres : FTAL: role testuser does not exist
```

I have tried switching the pg_hba file from md5 to trust, but that has not solved the issue.  Any thoughts?  The database server itself is running- I was able to connect to it using another tool. Also, the path has a reference to the postgres/bin directory.

Comment: what is your root user?    try createuser -U pgsql testuser

Comment: replacing pgsql with a superuser account as needed

Comment: please post as answer and I will accept.  How do I setup the pwd for the new user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify a super user account in order to create a user

```
createuser -U pgsql testuser
```

if you plan on using a password for this user you can use `-P` or `--pwprompt`

```
createuser -P  -U pgsql testuser
```

and it will prompt you for the password.

replace pgsql with a superuser account.